# Matching and deleting items in list of tuples

Tags: list, erlang, pattern-matching, tuples

I have a list of tuples, say,

```
[{x, a, y}, {x, b, y}].
```

Is there a built-in function (or can I use a combination of BIFs) to delete all tuples matching `{x, _, y}`, as in match and delete based on the first and third term in the tuples, ignoring the second?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [lists:filter/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#filter-2) function matches your need, e.g.

```
Ls = [{x,a,y}, {a,b,c}],
F = fun ({x,_,y}) -> false ; (_) -> true end,
lists:filter(F, Ls).
```

You can also use list comprehensions, which is like a combination of lists:map/2 and lists:filter/2.

```
[L || L <- Ls, F(L)]
```

If your predicate was the opposite, in that you only wanted those matching {x,_,y} you could write it as following, because the generator will filter out those not matching the pattern.

```
[L || {x,_,y}=L <- Ls]
```

Comment: I followed how you used lists:filter above but if i want to do that with a variable it does not work. 
Like this: 
F = fun({_,_Channel}) -> true; (_) -> false end,
ClientsOnChannel =  lists:filter(F(), NewServerState#server_st.client_channel),
It seems like Channel gets defined in the F scope. How do I get it to filter on "Channel" defined in the outer scope?